# Having trouble changing videos

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using html5 and jQuery.  I'm using the standard video player that comes with the Chrome browser.  I have two buttons that change the content of the src attribute in the source tag.  I know it changes when I open the Inspect Elements window and and drill down to the source tag  the src attribute changes every time I click a different button.  I don't know what command I can use to reload the video player UI in my script.
the code:

```
<head>
<title>video display</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
ul {position : absolute; top:20%; left:70%;}
li {list-style: none;}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#dogs").click(function() {
  $("#src").attr("src", "../video/dogs.webm");
 });
 $("#fish").click(function() {
  $("#src").attr("src", "../video/fish_dryer.webm");
 });
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><input id="fish" type="button" value="fish dryer" /></li>
        <li><input id="dogs" type="button" value="dogs" /></li>
    </ul>
<video controls>
   <source id="src" src="../video/fish_dryer.webm" type"video/webm">
</video>
</body>
```

you can see it online here: http://www.jimslounge.com/myStuff/changeVideo.html

//////////////  Fixed version  \\\\\\\\
just replace the video with yours and it will work.
**Thanks to Alexander Farkas for the solution!**

```
<head>
<title>change video</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
ul {position : absolute; top:20%; left:70%;}
li {list-style: none;}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#dogs").click(function() {
     $("#src")
      .prop("src", "../video/dogs.webm")
      .closest('video')
      .trigger('load');
      video.play();
  });
    $("#fish").click(function() {
    $("#src")
      .attr("src", "../video/fish_dryer.webm")
      .closest('video')
      .trigger('load');
      video.play();
 });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><input id="fish" type="button" value="fish dryer" /></li>
        <li><input id="dogs" type="button" value="dogs" /></li>
    </ul>
<video controls>
   <source id="src" src="">
</video>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `src` property instead of the corresponding attribute?

Comment: Could you show me an example of this src property?

Comment: for the jQuery API  - just change `attr` to `prop`. For the general  distinction - an attribute is  what you write in the HTML, a property is what actually applies. in the DOM API, `elem.src =` sets the property, `elem.setAttribute("src",` sets the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `load` method on the video element. The attr <-> prop change is not important, because attributes and properties reflect each other (99% of cases).

`$("#src")
    .prop("src", "../video/fish_dryer.webm")
    .closest('video')
    .trigger('load')
;`

Comment: I see attr and prop seem to be interchangeable here they both change the src but still nothing can't change video.  I used to do stuff like this in Flash sometimes building a video player from scratch sometimes passing parameters to an existing player. I wonder if there is a javsScript recipe anywhere for building a simple html5 video player?

Comment: Progress!! Your code does make a change I didn't copy it properly the first time. Now I can switch between fish-dryer and dogs but the controls are gone.

Comment: That did it all I had to do to make it work was add video.play(); at the end.